# Searching for shortest path

Tags: algorithm, path, depth-first-search, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

**Isn't it always better when searching for shortest path to use for connected nodes lists instead of grid?**

When using grid, you have to iterate over the grid every time, whereas using lists saves lots of time.

Comment: Depends:what if the connected path is a grid - like a lot of tile based games

Comment: Are you referring to an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix)? There are definitely very fast ways to traverse such a data structure.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean?

Comment: That's what I'm referring, sorry for being inaccurate

Comment: adjacent matrix allow to have distance between each point relatively easily for example.

Answer (score 0):

With adjacency matrix usually each check costs you O(n) time. It may be a bit slower than a list of connected nodes. However, you can do some fancy stuff with it. For example, if you want to delete a lot of edges, you can do it in O(1) using adjacency matrix (it may take a lot longer using a list of nodes depending on what data structure you use for it). Adjacency matrix is also a matrix. What do I mean by that? If you want to check in how many ways you can get from node A to node B in k steps, you can raise this matrix to the power of k, which is impossible to do with a list.